# Capturing optional data preceded by a comma

Tags: regex, ruby

I've got some text strings as follows that I'd like to match on, optionally capturing the "outcome" info if it is present:

```
0-0: Called Strike
0-1: Foul ball, location: 2F
0-2: Double, (Line Drive, 3D)
0-0: Foul Ball, location: 2F
0-1: Ball
1-1: Double, (Line Drive, 9LD)
0-0: Called Strike
0-1: Ball
1-1: Foul Ball, location: 2F
1-2: Ball
2-2: Ball
3-2: Ground out, 3-1 (Groundball, 34)
```

For the time being I have the following regex that I've been developing:

`^(?<balls>[0-3])-(?<strikes>[0-2]): (?<event>.*?(?=,|$))(?<outcome>.*$)`

Which works *pretty* well, but when it comes to the `outcome` component of the match, it includes all of the spaces in the data, so for a line like:

`0-1: Foul ball, location: 2F`, the `outcome` match is `, location: 2F`.

Any refinement of the match group `outcome` results in the un-matching of all of the lines that don't have extra data separated by the comma.

Can anyone help me finish the regex expression so that it will capture everything after a `,` and a `SPC` as `outcome` while still matching the columns that don't have the `,`?

Comment: Please edit to show the desired result for your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(?<balls>[0-3])-(?<strikes>[0-2]): (?<event>.*?(?=,|$))(?:, *(?<outcome>.*$))?`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3GQk58/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed make the last part optional by using an optional non capturing group `(?:,\h*(?<outcome>.*$))?` and match a comma followed by 0+ times a horizontal whitespace character using `\h*`.

But you could also update this part `.*?(?=,|$)` to use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^,\n\r]*` to prevent unnecessary backtracking.

Your expression might look like:

```
^(?<balls>[0-3])-(?<strikes>[0-2]): (?<event>[^,\n]*)(?:,\h*(?<outcome>.*$))?
                                             ^^^^^^^
```

See a [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/5RpgjB1t9uLtrb)

Instead of using `^` and `$` you might also opt for using `\A` and `\Z` [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az) to assert the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You have a listed a few events that may occur in a game of Baseball: called strike, ball, double and ground out. That is of course just the tip of the iceberg: fly out, foul out, single, triple, home run, sacrifice, error, stolen base, thrown out attempting steal, double play, triple play and others. For the event information to be useful each type of event must examined separately. To attempt to do that with a single regular expression is in my opinion folly. Below is an approach that might be considered. The `case` statement would have to be expanded greatly to include, among others, the events I mentioned above.

**Code**

```
def parse_events(arr)
  arr.map do |s|
    event = s[/\p{Lu}[\p{L} ]*(?=\,|\z)/].strip.downcase
    { event: event, count: s[0,3] }.merge(
    case event
    when "called strike", "ball"
      {} 
    when "foul ball"
      { location: s[/\d\p{L}+\z/] }
    when "double"  
      { type:     s[/(?<=\()[\p{L} ]+/].downcase,
        location: s[/\d\p{L}+(?=\)\z)/] }
    when "ground out"
      { sequence: s[/(?<=, )\d\-\d/],
        type:     s[/(?<=\()[\p{L} ]+/],
        location: s[/\d+(?=\)\z)/] }
    else  
      # raise exception
    end)
 end
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = <<-END.split("\n").map(&:strip)
0-0: Called Strike
0-1: Foul ball, location: 2F
0-2: Double, (Line Drive, 3D)
0-0: Foul Ball, location: 2F
0-1: Ball
1-1: Double, (Line Drive, 9LD)
0-0: Called Strike
0-1: Ball
1-1: Foul Ball, location: 2F
1-2: Ball
2-2: Ball
3-2: Ground out, 3-1 (Groundball, 34)
END
  #=> ["0-0: Called Strike",
  #    "0-1: Foul ball, location: 2F",
  #    "0-2: Double, (Line Drive, 3D)",
  #    "0-0: Foul Ball, location: 2F",
  #    "0-1: Ball",
  #    "1-1: Double, (Line Drive, 9LD)",
  #    "0-0: Called Strike",
  #    "0-1: Ball",
  #    "1-1: Foul Ball, location: 2F",
  #    "1-2: Ball",
  #    "2-2: Ball",
  #    "3-2: Ground out, 3-1 (Groundball, 34)"]
```

```
parse_events arr
  #=> [{:event=>"called strike", :count=>"0-0"},
  #    {:event=>"foul ball", :count=>"0-1", :location=>"2F"},
  #    {:event=>"double", :count=>"0-2", :type=>"line drive", :location=>"3D"},
  #    {:event=>"foul ball", :count=>"0-0", :location=>"2F"},
  #    {:event=>"ball", :count=>"0-1"},
  #    {:event=>"double", :count=>"1-1", :type=>"line drive", :location=>"9LD"},
  #    {:event=>"called strike", :count=>"0-0"},
  #    {:event=>"ball", :count=>"0-1"},
  #    {:event=>"foul ball", :count=>"1-1", :location=>"2F"},
  #    {:event=>"ball", :count=>"1-2"},
  #    {:event=>"ball", :count=>"2-2"},
  #    {:event=>"ground out", :count=>"3-2", :sequence=>"3-1",
  #     :type=>"Groundball", :location=>"34"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Call me old fashion, but this doesn't scream regex to me. It seems like it would be much easier to do this without it, granted I don't know your actual specs.

```rb
def get_stuff(str)
  score, details = str.split(':')
  balls, strikes = score.split('-')
  event, *outcome = details.split(',')
  return [balls, strikes, event.strip, outcome.join(' ').strip]
end

input = File.read('input.txt')
input.lines.each do |line|
  p get_stuff(line)
end
```

Outputs

```
["0", "0", "Called Strike", ""]
["0", "1", "Foul ball", "location"]
["0", "2", "Double", "(Line Drive  3D)"]
["0", "0", "Foul Ball", "location"]
["0", "1", "Ball", ""]
["1", "1", "Double", "(Line Drive  9LD)"]
["0", "0", "Called Strike", ""]
["0", "1", "Ball", ""]
["1", "1", "Foul Ball", "location"]
["1", "2", "Ball", ""]
["2", "2", "Ball", ""]
["3", "2", "Ground out", "3-1 (Groundball  34)"]
```